# What is causing the Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, webserver

I am creating a multi-threaded web server. When I run the client I receive a NullPointException. Why is this happening and what can be done to solve it?

> Concerning the suggestions that I should read the mentioned tutorial.  I have
>   tried to solve the problem with the help of it. I created a
>   constructor, but then I didn't know how to call the class: 
>   `theExecutor.execute(new Broadcaster (connection);`
>
> I also created a setter:  `public void setQuestions(String[]
>   questions) {
>               this.questions[1] = questions[1];}`
>
> That didn't help either. The String is initialized at the same place
>   as `questions[0]`. I can print out `questions[1]` in the console. It
>   get's its value from the ArrayList, but I do not know how to pass that
>   value to the HandleValidation class. That seems to be the problem.
>   If I have missed something in the tutorial that is an obvious solution, please tell me!

Here you can read exception message and the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at HandlleValidation.run(QuizServer.java:121)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```

**Here I am initializing the Executor which are handling the threads:**

```
public class QuizServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

ExecutorService theExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10000);
    ServerSocket quizSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

    try {
        while (true) {  //Skriver ut While True
            Socket connection = quizSocket.accept();
            theExecutor.execute(new Broadcaster(connection));
            theExecutor.execute(new HandlleValidation(connection));
        }
```

**The origin of the String questions[1] is in the Broadcaster class:**

I am using a get and set method to make it possible for the other inner class to work with

`String questions[];`

```
static class Broadcaster extends Thread {

    String quizFile = "src/qa.txt";
    private Socket connection;

    private PrintStream write;
    private String answer;
    private String questions[];
    int points = 0;

    public String[] getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }
```

> Here are the Strings `questions[0]` and `questions[1]`created:

```
while (true) {

                    for (String string : questionsList) {
                        String[] questions = string.split("/");
                        write.println(questions[0]);  //Printing out in client.
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(4000); //"Sleeping" between the lines.
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

**The NullPointerException occurs in the HandleValidation class:**

> `class HandlleValidation extends Thread {`

The problem is caused by this line:

```
  if (answer.equals(questions[1])) {
                points++;
                writer.println("RÄTT SVAR! Du har " + points + " poäng");
```

The Setter:

```
public void setQuestions(String[] questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
```

> I have tried to include as little of the code as possible to describe
>   the problem. I may be able to give more information if requested!

Comment: Where are you setting answer? answer seems null

Comment: `read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hv.getInputStream()));`
              
`answer = read.readLine();`

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have tried to solve the problem with the help of the tutorial. I created a constructor, but then I didn't know how to call the class:
`    theExecutor.execute(new Broadcaster (connection);`

I also created a setter:
 `public void setQuestions(String[] questions) {
            this.questions[1] = questions[1];
        }`

That didn't help either. The String is initialized at the same place as `questions[0]`. I can print out `questions[1] in the console. It get's its value from the ArrayList, but I do not know how to pass that value to the HandleValidation class.

Answer (score 1):

I see the variable in context of `for (String string: questionsList) {` and in another moment you use it in `if (answer.equals (questions [1])) {`: that is in other context, in other scope.

My suggestion is to declare that variable out of the **`for`** scope.